# Does proper/easy editor exist for .class java files?

Tags: java

As you see from the title my problem is editing .class files. I've been trying to compile .java to .class, but no luck! I'm getting strange errors. (Using DJ Java compiler/decompiler). My question is does an easy editor exist for .class files ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) disassembler/assembler (disclosure: I wrote it). This lets you edit classfiles at the bytecode level without a lossy (and potentially impossible) roundtrip to Java. You can even edit heavily obfuscated classes this way. Of course, this assumes that you're familiar with the classfile format.  If you don't understand bytecode, you're pretty much limited to either learning it (not that hard) or making do with decompilers.